# Invite un-committed followers to the Beta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

I want to `feature-request` what I said in a comment to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53989/will-a-proposals-beta-be-available-for-everyone/54003#54003).

Could followers who did not commit be invited to the private beta directly as committed users will be? (without needing the invitation of a committed user)

Comment: Maybe followers who also posted or voted on questions? I followed some proposals without participating, I was just interested in seeing how they evolved and wanted to remind my self to check on them from time to time.

Comment: @Tim, If you are following it then (as you say) would be interested to know when it reaches the beta. Anyway, it's an invitation, not an obligation.

Comment: This would be very nice. There are 4 proposals that I am really interested in, but I can only commit to three.

Comment: Somehow, I don't feel this is status-completed. Another feature is implemented, but it is not that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now invite other people you know to a site during a private beta by simply entering their email address after you have joined the site.  This will replace the old "under construction" logo that was taking that spot.

Answer (score 6):

We will have a very limited invitation system during the private beta -- so committers can invite a few folks of their choosing to the site during the period that the private beta runs.

But really, the goal is to get out of private beta ASAP.

(however, yes, it is possible *in theory* that some sites could reach private beta and fail to exit, because they're not generating enough activity..)

Comment: Is that how you plan to get your hands on my generous bounty?

Comment: That is exactly what I call a fuzzy answer. A few is more than 1 but how much?

Answer (score 4):

Now that the [Food and Cooking proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking) is in [private beta](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) , I find myself wanting to invite some of my friends/family to participate in the site. Maybe each committer could get 5 invites or something to give out?

Answer (score 2):

This may require more careful consideration than it seems at first glance.

One of the reasons to limit people to 3 commitments is to avoid having beta participants spreading themselves too thin - it's worthwhile limiting their participation so they focus more closely on the sites they believe they can contribute the most.

There are ways to get into the beta without committing, but making it trivial or easy to do so may actually be counterproductive.

Comment: If they let us commit to 5 or 6 IBM may pull their ads citing a sharp decline in employee production.

Comment: It will be opened to anyone from the second week, I just don't want to miss the first.

Comment: @Tim Link to ads? I manage to escape most advertising.