# Can't unfollow a proposal in beta

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, following-proposal

I'd like to unfollow web applications, but I can't (I could when it was in commitment).

I started following it in the hopes of [being invited to the private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54146/invite-un-committed-followers-to-the-beta), but that didn't happen.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to un-follow? It's in beta so it's not generating any activity on Area 51, and, unlike committing, you can follow as many proposals as you want.

Comment: @Kyle, no, not particular reason, just to order my followed list

Comment: +1 I've now got 3 proposals now in beta "stuck" on my user profile page. Arghhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposals in beta can now be followed and unfollowed.

**EDIT:** We re-disabled following and unfollowing beta proposals (in response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59886/can-we-make-it-so-that-unfollowing-a-beta-site-doesnt-affect-the-other-persons-r)), but they are now hidden from your "Followed" list.