# How can I unfollow a proposal that is in Beta in Area 51?

Tags: feature-request, support, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t unfollow a proposal in beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55841/cant-unfollow-a-proposal-in-beta)

I know this question has been asked [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55841/cant-unfollow-a-proposal-in-beta), but nothing has been done about it, and I want the problem solved (or an existing solution pointed out to me).

I have 2 proposals that are currently on public beta but that I am also following, and I really don't want to have them repeated on my profile. The problem is, once a proposal goes to beta, you are stuck with it and can't unfollow.

Here is a picture of my [profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/6617/vivi):

[image]

What I want to do is to be able to un-follow Mathematics and Tex, Latex and friends so that my profile would be cleaner and the proposals that are not elsewhere have more prominence.

What can I do, or what can you do for me, so that this issue is resolved?

Comment: You could always put a bounty on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now implemented, as seen in the [question you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55841/cant-unfollow-a-proposal-in-beta).