# Can we make it so that Unfollowing a beta site doesn't affect the other persons rep?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, reputation, area-51

So after reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55841/cant-unfollow-a-proposal-in-beta) [and this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59421/how-can-i-unfollow-a-proposal-that-is-in-beta-in-area-51) I was like yay! Now I don't need all that clutter on my Area51 profile page because I can un-follow Mathematics and GameDevelopment. But the problem is this: once you un-follow something the users rep goes down because that site does not have as many followers. Don't you think that if a person has been following since the definition stage and has not un-followed up to the beta stage the person that proposed the Q&A should not lose rep because of the un-follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of having to unfollow a proposal, it should be possible to simply hide those sites that are in beta.

Comment: Sure that works too.

Comment: This could work. So how about if we re-disabled following/unfollowing beta proposals, and then hide sites in beta from your "followed" list?

Comment: Sure, sounds good to me.

Comment: Ok, we just implemented this.