# Is commitment necessary to participate in beta (as of June 2015)?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase, site-proposal, commitment-phase

There's this proposal for a new S.E. site which is about to enter the beta phase.

It reads

> This proposal is in: Commitment
>
> A successful site needs people to commit to use it.
> This proposal is 100% complete. Committed users will be invited to the private beta soon.

I'd like to participate in the beta but I don't want to commit (due to a full name being required).

Will I be unable to participate in the beta if I don't commit?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Thanks, I searched before asking, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54146/invite-un-committed-followers-to-the-beta

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Perhaps it's not so helpful to close as a duplicate of a question with outdated answers, while this one has a correct one. I suggest closing as a duplicate in the opposite direction.

Comment: You could just put a space in there btw, or your current display name?

Answer (score 12):

> Will I be unable to participate in the beta if I don't commit?

That used to be the case.

Currently, you can go to the Area 51 proposal - once it has launched as a private beta there will be a link to the new site. Following the link will let you sign up to the site and participate during the private beta.