# Will beta Stack Exchange sites be open to non-commiters?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stackexchange-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will a proposal’s Beta be available for everyone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53989/will-a-proposals-beta-be-available-for-everyone)

While I may not be able to supply the requisite commitment to fully participate in some of the Stack Exchange candidates I would like to nonetheless participate.  Will beta Stack Exchanges be open to non-committers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first week is a [closed private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53989/will-a-proposals-beta-be-available-for-everyone/54003#54003) (only people who committed and people they invite) and after that it is an open beta.

Comment: What about people who followed the proposal but didn't commit?

Comment: @George They aren't automatically invited yet, but there's a [feature request for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54146/invite-un-committed-followers-to-the-beta).